# Choice between options in indexOf function

Tags: javascript, arguments, selection, logical-operators, indexof

i want to have a selection between different options in javascript "**indexOf**" function in a if structure. What is the best way to solve it...
This example does not work:

```
if( str.indexOf( "twitter" || "facebook" || "youtube")!=-1 ){  
//my code goes here
}
```

We can use this codes to work
But it isn't ideal...

> var str="my profile in facebook";
>   if (str.indexOf("twitter")!=-1 ||
>   str.indexOf("youtube")!=-1 || str.indexOf("facebook")!=-1){ //codes goes
>   here }

Comment: Keep in mind, that `"twitter tweets".indexOf("twitter")` is `0` and therefore would be falsey. I.e. the code in your if-statement would not execute

Comment: Also note that `"twitter" || "facebook" || "youtube"` evaluates to "twitter". If you want to test if any of those are found, `["twitter", "facebook", "youtube"].some(substr => -1 != str.indexOf(substr))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a function for that.

```
function contains(str, substring) {
  return str.indexOf(substring) > -1;
}

if(contains(str, "twitter") || contains(str, "facebook") || contains(str, "youtube")) {
  // your code here
}
```

Or, if you want it to be more concise while programming, use the following:

```
function containsAny(str) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
           .slice(1)
           .some(function(substring) {
             return str.indexOf(substring) > -1
            });
 }

 if(containsAny(str, "twitter", "facebook", "youtube")) {
   // your code here
 }
```

**Edit**: As to your question for less code, with ES6, you can do:

```
const containsAny = (str, ...args) => [...args].slice(1).some(s => str.indexOf(s) > -1)
```

Comment: Your twice solution is good. thanks. Is any way to solve my question by less codes?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you are looking for, a solution can be:

```
if( str.indexOf( "twitter")!=-1 || str.indexOf( "facebook")!=-1 || str.indexOf( "youtube")!=-1 ){  
    //my code goes here
}
```

Comment: Now I edited my question and clarified I don't want this way. this way is not recommended for more options.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this...

```js
var media = ["twitter", "facebook", "youtube"];
if(media.includes(str) {
//your code
}
```

Comment: This tests whether `str` is one of those three, not if it _contains_ one of those three.